# Why file row count is more than len(dataframe)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Good morning,

I'm new to python and data analysis world, so bear with me. I've been trying to understand why when counting file rows it gives  the right answer but after converting to dataframe and counting len(datafarme), it gives a rowcount-1.

I'm sure it's simple but I've googled it for about two hours and I didn't find an answer yet, so would you kindly explain this to me:

```
import pandas as pd

filename = 'amazon_labelled.txt'
with open(filename, encoding="utf8") as f:
    row_count = sum(1 for line in f)
print(row_count)  # 1000

csv = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(csv)
print(df1.shape[0])  # 999
print(len(df1))  # 999
print(len(df1.index))  # 999
```

**EDIT:**
It seems that when converting txt to csv file, some lines went missing:

```
filename = 'imdb_labelled.txt'
with open(filename, encoding="utf8") as f:
    row_count = sum(1 for line in f)
print(row_count)  # 1000

csv = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', header=None)
print(csv.index)  # RangeIndex(start=0, stop=748, step=1)
print(csv)
```

I'm wondering now, does it have something to do with using sep='\t'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason is first row of csv is converted to columns, for avoid it and set columns names by range use `header=None` parameter:

```
filename = 'amazon_cells_labelled.txt'
with open(filename, encoding="utf8") as f:
    row_count = sum(1 for line in f)
print(row_count)  # 1000

#first row of csv is first row of data 
df1 = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', header=None)

print(df1.shape[0])  # 1000
print(len(df1))  # 1000
print(len(df1.index))  # 1000
```

Your code:

```
#first row of csv is converted to columns names
df1 = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t')
```

EDIT: In next files is used `"`, so pandas incorrect parsing. For avoid read starting by `"` and then next rows ending by `"` like one row use `quoting=3` parameter for `quoting=None`:

```
filename = 'imdb_labelled.txt'
with open(filename, encoding="utf8") as f:
    row_count = sum(1 for line in f)
print(row_count)  # 1000

df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', header=None, quoting=3)
print(len(df.index))  
1000
```

Comment: Thank you sir, but when I tested it on another file, it wasn't working:

filename = 'imdb_labelled.txt'
with open(filename, encoding="utf8") as f:
    row_count = sum(1 for line in f)
print(row_count)  # 1000

csv = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', header=None)
df = pd.DataFrame(csv)
print(df.shape[0])  # 748
print(len(df))  # 748
print(len(df.index))  # 748

Have any ideas?

Comment: @LeenAli - Is possible share csv by `dropbox`, `gdocs` or simiaar?

Comment: @LeenAli - I think if not confidenta data

Comment: Sure sir, I got it from Kaggle:
https://www.kaggle.com/marklvl/sentiment-labelled-sentences-data-set
I appreciate your help, Thank you!

Comment: @LeenAli - for me working wery well, 4 times 1000 returned.

Comment: That's awkward! Would you kindly show me your code? I must be doing something wrong here. and thank you again.

Comment: @LeenAli - there is only change `df1 = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', header=None)` and removed `df1 = pd.DataFrame(csv)`, but if also use `csv = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', header=None)` `df1 = pd.DataFrame(csv)` get 1000 4 times. Added code to answer

Comment: @LeenAli - If still problem what is your pandas version? Tested in `pandas 1.2.3`

Comment: Mine is also 1.2.3, and I tun another test, please see my edited question above. thanks.

Comment: @LeenAli - Yes, same problem, I find it, answer was edited.

Comment: Yes this is it! Thank you so much sir for your time and effor.

Comment: @LeenAli - Ya, it was very interesting problem. Coder have to be here Sherlock Holmes ;)

Comment: ;) – ;) – ;) – ;) –

Answer (score 1):

### Code

```
import pandas as pd
f= open("amazon_labelled.txt","w+")
for i in range(10):
     f.write("This is line %d\r\n" % (i+1))
filename = 'amazon_labelled.txt'
with open(filename, encoding="utf8") as f:
    row_count = sum(1 for line in f)
print(row_count)  # 1000

csv = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(csv)
#print(df1.shape[0])  # 999
#print(len(df1))  # 999
#print(len(df1.index))  # 999
f1= open("amazon_labelled.txt","r+")
fl = f1.readlines()
print("this is the file lines" )
for i in fl :
  print(i)
print("this is your cvs file ",csv)
```

### Output

10
this is the file lines
This is line 1

This is line 2

This is line 3

This is line 4

This is line 5

This is line 6

This is line 7

This is line 8

This is line 9

This is line 10

this is your cvs file

This is line 1

0   This is line 2

1   This is line 3

2   This is line 4

3   This is line 5

4   This is line 6

5   This is line 7

6   This is line 8

7   This is line 9

8  This is line 10

your enumerate method is wrong

Comment: Thank you sir, but I didn't get your answer and also applying your code returned these result:
20 ==> print(row_count)
9 ==> print(df1.shape[0]) 
9 ==> print(len(df1))
9 ==> print(len(df1.index))

Comment: Please see my edited question above, maybe you could explain it to me?

Comment: @LeenAli I couldn't understand "It seems that when converting txt to csv file, some lines went missing:" The code I posted prints data frame and there is no missing line in it

Comment: Thank you sir for taking of your time.
Please see @jezrael answer as it explains the whole thing.
Thank you.